# Replace just Filtered rows in Pandas DataFrame for another Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with an Dataframe that have latitude and longitude columns. I found some problems with part of this dataframe. Filtering the columns = latitude and longitude with problem i found:

The Orginal Dataframe filtered by latitude and longitude: df17

input:

```
 df17[['latitude','longitude']].info()
```

output:

```
  <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 204395 entries, 431458 to 635852
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count   Dtype  
---  ------     --------------   -----  
 0   latitude   204395 non-null  float64
 1   longitude  204395 non-null  float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 4.7 MB
```

I've been filtered the values latitude and longitude that doesn't make any sense for me...

input:

```
df17.loc[((df17['longitude']>-35)|(df17['longitude']<-71)|(df17['latitude']>5)|(df17['latitude']<-34)),['latitude','longitude']]
```

output:

```
latitude    longitude
431460  -23.369520  309.935131
431461  -23.369520  309.935131
431609  -8.057838   -34.882897
431610  -8.057838   -34.882897
431620  -12.274928  -415.558205
... ... ...
635465  -7.179325   -34.900260
635527  -7.915741   -34.898170
635528  -7.915741   -34.898170
635583  -7.128831   -34.952970
635584  -7.128831   -34.952970
4935 rows × 2 columns
```

So I've been working on those 4935 rows and fixed that, creating a new DataFrame = df_latilon

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4935 entries, 0 to 4934
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------     --------------  -----  
 0   Latitude   4935 non-null   float64
 1   Longitude  4935 non-null   float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 77.2 KB
```

Now I would like to replace the rows in main Data Frame df17 with those fixed (from df_latitlon), but I'm not sure how to replace only filtered rows in df_17 main data frame.

I've been tried in that way:

Input:

```
df17.loc[((df17['longitude']>-35)|(df17['longitude']<-71)|(df17['latitude']>5)|(df17['latitude']<-34)),['latitude','longitude']]=df_latilon[['latitude','longitude']]
```

Output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 204395 entries, 431458 to 635852
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count   Dtype  
---  ------     --------------   -----  
 0   latitude   199460 non-null  float64
 1   longitude  199460 non-null  float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 4.7 MB
```

But it not worked, and looks that those 4935 rows were droped from Data Frame ..

Can someone help me with that ?

Thanks so much....

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html

Comment: You probably need to add minimal examples of df17 and df_latlon - enough for your filters to work. If you used the same filter in the assignment that you used to *make* df_latlon, it should have worked.  `But it not worked` doesn't mean much to us without any data.  Please read [mre]. ... [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: If you didn't change the index of df_latlon maybe `df17.loc[df_latlon.index,['latitude','longitude']]=df_latilon[['Latitude','Longitude']]` will work.

Comment: Are you confident that your original filter is correct?

Comment: i've been changing the question, I hope it is clearer now, sorry if it was confusing.

Comment: @wwii unfortunately for the df_latlon i have new index [1,2,3,4];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Not an answer.** Cannot reproduce your problem.
My mre - I added a few rows that do not meet the condition:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

f = io.StringIO('''index        latitude    longitude
431460  -23.369520  309.935131
431461  -23.369520  309.935131
431609  -8.057838   -34.882897
431610  -8.057838   -34.882897
431620  -12.274928  -415.558205
635465  -7.179325   -34.900260
635527  -7.915741   -34.898170
999990  -7.128831   -36.952970
999991  -7.128831   -37.952970
999992  -7.128831   -38.952970
635528  -7.915741   -34.898170
635583  -7.128831   -34.952970
635584  -7.128831   -34.952970''')

df = df17 = pd.read_csv(f,sep='\s+',index_col=0)
print(f'df17:\n{df17}\n****')

df17:
         latitude   longitude
index                        
431460 -23.369520  309.935131
431461 -23.369520  309.935131
431609  -8.057838  -34.882897
431610  -8.057838  -34.882897
431620 -12.274928 -415.558205
635465  -7.179325  -34.900260
635527  -7.915741  -34.898170
999990  -7.128831  -36.952970
999991  -7.128831  -37.952970
999992  -7.128831  -38.952970
635528  -7.915741  -34.898170
635583  -7.128831  -34.952970
635584  -7.128831  -34.952970
****

condition = ((df17['longitude']>-35)|(df17['longitude']<-71)|(df17['latitude']>5)|(df17['latitude']<-34))
print(f'condition:\n{condition}\n****')

condition:
index
431460     True
431461     True
431609     True
431610     True
431620     True
635465     True
635527     True
999990    False
999991    False
999992    False
635528     True
635583     True
635584     True
dtype: bool
****

df_fixed = df17.loc[condition,['latitude','longitude']] * 20
print(f'df_fixed:\n{df_fixed}\n****')

df_fixed:
         latitude   longitude
index                        
431460 -467.39040  6198.70262
431461 -467.39040  6198.70262
431609 -161.15676  -697.65794
431610 -161.15676  -697.65794
431620 -245.49856 -8311.16410
635465 -143.58650  -698.00520
635527 -158.31482  -697.96340
635528 -158.31482  -697.96340
635583 -142.57662  -699.05940
635584 -142.57662  -699.05940
****

df17.loc[condition,['latitude','longitude']] = df_fixed
print(f'df17:\n{df17}\n****')

df17:
          latitude   longitude
index                         
431460 -467.390400  6198.70262
431461 -467.390400  6198.70262
431609 -161.156760  -697.65794
431610 -161.156760  -697.65794
431620 -245.498560 -8311.16410
635465 -143.586500  -698.00520
635527 -158.314820  -697.96340
999990   -7.128831   -36.95297
999991   -7.128831   -37.95297
999992   -7.128831   -38.95297
635528 -158.314820  -697.96340
635583 -142.576620  -699.05940
635584 -142.576620  -699.05940
****
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I solved it using pd.update
so first you have to rename your filtered dataframe:
Let´s name it like df_wrong.
As I´m not sure what is the index from df17 you might want to reset its index.

```
df17.reset_index(inplace=True)
df_wrong= df17.loc[((df17['longitude']>-35)|(df17['longitude']<-71)| 
(df17['latitude']>5)| 
(df17['latitude']<-34)),['latitude','longitude']]
```

Then you use the index of df_wrong to identify the rows you want to replace, and set that index in your corrected dataframe (df_latilon)

```
df_latilon.set_index(df_wrong.index(), inplace=True)
```

Then you just use the function update of pandas

```
df17.update(df_latilon)
```

This function will replace the values of df17 with the values of df_latilon that corresponds to the columns and index.